# Meaning of Roll sevens or Rolling sevens

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idioms

What is the meaning of the phrase " ***you rolled them sevens with nothing to lose*** " ?

In the song entitled " [The weary kind](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/crazyheart/thewearykind.htm) " which is a sound track of the "Crazy heart" movie , there is a line that i can't understand.

```
    Your heart's on the loose

    You rolled them sevens with nothing to lose,

    there's ain't no place for the weary kind
```

Could you please help me to understand that phrase ?

Comment: It's a reference to to the dice game "Craps" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craps

Comment: I am still confused :( is there someone to explain simply the meaning of the phrase for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jim mentioned, it's a reference to *craps*.

The point is that rolling a seven (two dice together having seven eyes up) can be both a winning or a losing throw in this game, depending on the timing. It is also the most common throw.

So *rolling them sevens* doesn't mean winning or losing, it means *playing* or *gambling*.

Gambling with nothing to lose has some connotations: it either means you cannot lose the bet - or it means you *have* nothing left that you can lose. Normally you cannot enter a gambling game if you cannot put up the stakes, so if you are gambling while you have nothing to lose, you are completely broke and risking it all. Not very careful or *weary* :)

So, *you rolled them sevens with nothing to lose* means as much as *you went on playing even though you couldn't / shouldn't have*.

---

As for why you would normally stop if you have nothing left to lose, as medica asked, the last thing that you have (otherwise actively playing is difficult) might be your life. Since serious gamblers don't like to win the game and win nothing for it (which happens if the loser has nothing to pay them with), they may well consider it fair to relieve you 
from that life. So, while it *may* seem that gambling with nothing to lose is risk-free, it may be a lot riskier than gambling when you have money!

Comment: If they had nothing to lose, why should they have stopped? Your last sentence is confusing). +1 however. Perhaps you can explain?

Comment: @oerkelens : Thank you man for your time . I think people like you that try to decode a lyric for a non English person really deserves to be appreciated . thanks again:)

Comment: @siamak Thank you. I actually owe much of my understanding of English to the decoding of lyrics.